# Copy values inside group with pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a df in pyspark similar to this one. I need to copy values inside the groups, without leaving empty strings.

```
+---------------+-----+----+
|values_to_copy |group|flag|
+---------------+-----+----+
|        value_1|   31|   1|
|               |   31|   1|
|        value_1|   31|   1|
|        value_2|  152|   1|
|               |  152|   1|
|               |  153|   1|
|        value_3|  153|   1|
|        value_4|  154|   1|
|               |  154|   1|
+---------------+-----+----+
```

And I need output like this one.

```
+---------------+-----+----+
|values_to_copy |group|flag|
+---------------+-----+----+
|        value_1|   31|   1|
|        value_1|   31|   1|
|        value_1|   31|   1|
|        value_2|  152|   1|
|        value_2|  152|   1|
|        value_3|  153|   1|
|        value_3|  153|   1|
|        value_4|  154|   1|
|        value_4|  154|   1|
+---------------+-----+----+
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dataframe like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame((
    ("value_1", 31, 1),
    (None, 31, 1),
    ("value_1", 31, 1),
    ("value_2", 152, 1),
    (None, 152, 1),
    (None, 153, 1),
    ("value_3", 153, 1),
    ("value_4", 154, 1),
    (None, 154, 1),
),
    ("values_to_copy", "group", "flag"))

df.show()

# output
+--------------+-----+----+
|values_to_copy|group|flag|
+--------------+-----+----+
|       value_1|   31|   1|
|          null|   31|   1|
|       value_1|   31|   1|
|       value_2|  152|   1|
|          null|  152|   1|
|          null|  153|   1|
|       value_3|  153|   1|
|       value_4|  154|   1|
|          null|  154|   1|
+--------------+-----+----+
```

You first need to define the window which will be applied:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window().partitionBy("group").orderBy("group", F.desc("values_to_copy"))
```

And finally, you could use the following syntax to achieve what you want:

```
(
    df.withColumn("filled", 
                  F.first("values_to_copy", ignorenulls=True).over(w)
                 )
    .show()
)

# output
+--------------+-----+----+-------+
|values_to_copy|group|flag| filled|
+--------------+-----+----+-------+
|       value_1|   31|   1|value_1|
|       value_1|   31|   1|value_1|
|          null|   31|   1|value_1|
|       value_3|  153|   1|value_3|
|          null|  153|   1|value_3|
|       value_4|  154|   1|value_4|
|          null|  154|   1|value_4|
|       value_2|  152|   1|value_2|
|          null|  152|   1|value_2|
+--------------+-----+----+-------+
```

In fact, in this example, you could use either `F.last` or `F.first` with the same result because in each group you have only one value in `values_to_copy` column.

So if you have a group with values:

```
value_1
value_1
null
```

When you use `F.first` -> you will get `value_1`.

When you use `F.last` -> you will get `null`, but because of param `ignorenulls=True` you go to the next value which is `value_1`.

The difference will come when you have a few different values within a single group, for example for `group=31` you will have `values_to_copy`:

```
value_2
value_1
value_1
null
```

Here `F.first` would return `value_2` populated for entire group and `F.last` would return `value_1`.

Comment: `ignorenulls=True` is genius :)

Comment: Thanks a lot  it worked.